# How to rescue a CentOS installation which doesn't appear in UEFI

Tags: linux, boot, centos, multi-boot, uefi

I am attempting to set up dual-boot Windows and CentOS on my laptop.

I did a fresh Windows install, freed up about 128 GB on my data drive (using diskmgmt), made an installer USB drive and ran the installer. Everything went correctly in the installer, and it asked me to reboot.

When I did so, however, only the external USB showed up as a boot option! I have tried changing the secure boot settings in the UEFI BIOS, however I cannot make either Windows or Linux appear as boot options.

The bootable USB does give me the option to “Rescue a CentOS Installation” — it seems to be able to find it, but I'm not good enough with the terminal to know how to even boot it, let alone make it show up in the boot options in the BIOS. I don't want to make the issue worse. How do I fix this?

Comment: Was Windows 10 working before this happen? If yes, then you can just delete the GRUB and fix EFI files in Windows. Search "fix EFI files in windows" in Google or Superuser.

Comment: Should I delete GRUB first? How do I do that?

Comment: I have just tried fixing EFI in windows, my SYSTEM drive had no letter so I assigned one, but I couldn't do BCD rebuild because the drive was "indistinguishable" and I don't know how to fix it.